# Swift NSURLConnection put HTTP Entity

Tags: swift, http-headers, httpentity

i want to put a `HTTP Entity` ( W3.org [link](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html) ) extra using swift `NSURLConnection`.

i put a `Http Header` named `entity-body` with my `urlEncoded` key value in `NSMutableURLRequest` but not working !

**Edit**

```
var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:URL)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("{ my JSON Data }", forHTTPHeaderField: "entity-body")
```

Comment: Show us how u add the entity-body to header...

Comment: And explain what you mean by "not working"

Comment: "not working" mean url response is "json is not set"

Comment: How do you see it is not set?

Comment: @Arbitur webService is a valid and working webService that always answer to this requests , the problem is in application side and i am sure ! , if you know something please write about it ! , thanks

Comment: Based on that document it seems you have to include a content-length and entity-header for entity-body to work.

Comment: @Arbitur if you are sure it will work , just post an answer. thank you

Comment: Im not sure at all, havent tested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally , i found a working answer !

object is my JSON stored in a swift String.

```
var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:URL)
request.setValue(String(count(object)), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length");
request.HTTPBody = object.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
```